# AWK write to a file based on number of fields in csv

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to iterate over a csv file and discard the rows while writing to a file which doesnt have all columns in a row.

I have an input file `mtest.csv` like this

```
IP@#Process@#Device@#ID
TestIP1@#TestProcess2@#TestDevice1@#TestID1
TestIP2@#TestProcess2@#TestDevice2
TestIP3@#TestProcess3@#TestDevice3@#TestID3
```

But I am trying to only write those row records where all the 4 columns are present. The output should not have the TestIP2 column complete row as it has 3 columns.

Sample output should look like this:

```
IP@#Process@#Device@#ID
TestIP1@#TestProcess2@#TestDevice1@#TestID1
TestIP3@#TestProcess3@#TestDevice3@#TestID3
```

I used to do like this to get all the columns earlier but it writes the TestIP2 row as well which has 3 columns

```
awk -F "\@#" '{print $1"\@#"substr($2,1,50)"\@#"substr($3,1,50)"\@#"substr($4,1,50)}' mtest.csv >output2.csv
```

But when I try to ensure that it writes to file when all 4 columns are present, it doesn't work

```
awk -F "\@#", 'NF >3 {print $1"\@#"substr($2,1,50)"\@#"substr($3,1,50)"\@#"substr($4,1,50); exit}' mtest.csv >output2.csv
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is probably `awk -F "@#" 'NF>3 {print $0}'`

Answer (score 2):

You are making things harder than it need to be. All you need to do is check `NF==4` to output any records containing four fields. Your total `awk` expression would be:

```
awk -F'@#' NF==4 < mtest.csv
```

(**note:** the default action by `awk` is `print` so there is no explicit `print` required.)

**Example Use/Output**

With your sample input in `mtest.csv`, you would receive:

```
$ awk -F'@#' NF==4 < mtest.csv
IP@#Process@#Device@#ID
TestIP1@#TestProcess2@#TestDevice1@#TestID1
TestIP3@#TestProcess3@#TestDevice3@#TestID3
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks David and vukung

Both your solutions are okay.I want to write to a file so that i can trim the length of each field as well

I think this below statement works out

```
awk -F "@#" 'NF>3 {print $1"\@#"substr($2,1,50)"\@#"substr($3,1,2)"\@#"substr($4,1,3)}'  mtest.csv >output2.csv
```